# Trying to echo </ul> for certain parts of an array

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, mysqli

I am trying to echo category names and list any post name that has that category in a bootstrap list-group. the problem I run into is echoing the closing ul So I can start a new ul. So how can I echo the closing ul at the end of each category.This is what I have right now. Let me know if you have any better ideas. Right now I am just getting a list like so: The end result would be storing each category in its own collapsible list panel http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp#collapse1

```
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ul>
```

the following is my attempted code.

```
<?php

   $query = "SELECT post_category,post_title
               FROM posts 
           ORDER BY post_category";
   $select_categories_sidebars = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
?>
<h4>Blog Categories</h4>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <ul class="list-group">
        <?php
             $title = "";
             while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_categories_sidebars)) {
                 if ($row['post_category'] != $title) {
                      echo '<ul><li class="list-group-item">'.$row['post_category'].'</li><br>';
                      $title = $row['post_category'];
                 }
                 echo '<li class="list-group-item">'.$row['post_title']</li>;
             }
?>
```

Comment: You are missing an ending `ul`, don't you?

Comment: Where are you saying I need that?

Comment: at the end, after closeing the PHP mode ( `?>`)

Comment: That was in my original code I just forgot to paste it in. but it still echoes out like the example above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood the question, but I bet that you're missing some `</ul>`.

Try this:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT post_category,post_title
            FROM posts 
        ORDER BY post_category";
$select_categories_sidebars = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
?>
<h4>Blog Categories</h4>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-12">
    <ul class="list-group">
    <?php
         $title = "";
         $someItem=false;
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_categories_sidebars)) {
             if ($row['post_category'] != $title) {
                  if ($someItem)
                  {
                      echo '</ul>';
                  }
                  $someItem=true;
                  echo '<ul><li class="list-group-item">'.$row['post_category'].'</li><br>';
                  $title = $row['post_category'];
             }
             echo '<li class="list-group-item">'.$row['post_title']</li>;
         }
 ?>
 </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: This ends up basically echoing out my first example above

Comment: No, it adds a `</ul>` after every category change

Comment: Oh.. Sorry I missed that

Comment: Glad to have helped you!

Answer (score 0):

You need an `</ul>` at the end of each list like shown below. You need to modify your code so that every list always starts with an `<ul>` and ends with an `</ul>` and every list item starts with `<li>` and ends with an `</li>`. You will have to make a separate query for each category.

```html
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ul>
```